# Xamarin Android Recycler View Click Event to new Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

hice este recycler view que ya logre llenar con datos y todo pero no consigo cachar el evento click, necesito cacharlo y navegar hacia un nuevo activit mandando el id de mi objecto `Contact` alguien sabe en que estoy fallando?

Esto lo tengo en mi mainActivity

```
 private void SetUpRecyclerView()
    {
        
        listSource.Clear();
        listSource = mydb.GetListContacts();
        contactsDataList
            .SetLayoutManager(new Android.Support.V7.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(contactsDataList.Context));
        RecyclerViewAdapterContacts adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterContacts(listSource);
        contactsDataList.SetAdapter(adapter);
       
    }
```

Este es mi clase RecyclerView adapter

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapterContacts : RecyclerView.Adapter//, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public EventHandler<ContactAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemClick;
    public EventHandler<ContactAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemLongClick;
    List<Contact> items;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterContacts(List<Contact> data)
    {
        items = data;            
    }

    public override int ItemCount => items.Count;

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder, int position)
    {
        //var item = items[position];
        var holder = viewholder as ContactAdapterViewHolder;

       holder.email_row.Text = items[position].Email;
        holder.password_row.Text = items[position].Password;
   
     //((ContactAdapterViewHolder)holder).ItemView.Click += Contact_Click;
    }
                 
    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.contact_row, parent, false);
        var vholder = new ContactAdapterViewHolder(itemView, OnClick, OnLongClick);
        
    }

    private void OnLongClick(ContactAdapterClickEventArgs args) =>  ItemLongClick?.Invoke(this,args);
    

    private void OnClick(ContactAdapterClickEventArgs args) => ItemClick?.Invoke(this, args);

   
}


public class ContactAdapterClickEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public View View { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}


public class ContactAdapterViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView email_row { get; set; }
    public TextView password_row { get; set; }

    public ContactAdapterViewHolder(View itemView, Action<ContactAdapterClickEventArgs> clickListener,
        Action<ContactAdapterClickEventArgs> longClickListener) : base(itemView)
    {

        email_row = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.email_row);
        password_row = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.password_row);


        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => clickListener(new ContactAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
        itemView.LongClick += (sender, e) => longClickListener(new ContactAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok dejo esto por si a alguien le sirve

```
{
public class RecyclerViewAdapterContacts : RecyclerView.Adapter //, View.IOnClickListener
{
    public EventHandler<ContactAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemClick;
 
    IList<Contact> _items;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterContacts(IList<Contact> data)
    {
        this._items = data;
    }
    public override int ItemCount => _items.Count;


    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder, int position)
    {           
        var holder = viewholder as ContactAdapterViewHolder;           
        holder.email_row.Text = _items[position].Email;            
        var subpass = _items[position].Password;            
        holder.password_row.Text = "****" + subpass.Substring(subpass.Length - 4);
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.contact_row, parent, false);
        var vholder = new ContactAdapterViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
        return vholder;
    }
    
    private void OnClick(ContactAdapterClickEventArgs args)  
    {
        var contact = _items[args.Position];
        args.Contact = contact;
        ItemClick?.Invoke(this, args);
    }       
}

public class ContactAdapterClickEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public View View { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class ContactAdapterViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView email_row { get; set; }
    public TextView password_row { get; set; }

    public ContactAdapterViewHolder(View itemView, Action<ContactAdapterClickEventArgs> clickListener) : base(itemView)
    {
        email_row = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.email_row);
        password_row = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.password_row);
        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => clickListener(new ContactAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });            
    }
}
```

}

y en mi mainAcitivity

```
  private void SetUpRecyclerView()
    {

        _constactsSource.Clear();
        _contctsRecycleView.HasFixedSize = true;
        _constactsSource = _contactsService.GetListContacts();
        _contctsRecycleView
            .SetLayoutManager(new Android.Support.V7.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(_contctsRecycleView.Context));
        RecyclerViewAdapterContacts adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterContacts(_constactsSource);
        adapter.ItemClick += OnLonClick;
        _contctsRecycleView.SetAdapter(adapter);
       
    }

    private void OnLonClick(object sender, ContactAdapterClickEventArgs e)

    {
        var intent = new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(UpdateLocalActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("MyLocalID", e.Contact.Id.ToString());
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

Y listo todo bien.

Comment: Adjunto el link que me ayudo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613746/start-activity-from-recyclerview-xamarin